# How to Open Datalist Link Button in New Tab in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, datalist, linkbutton

I have a `DataList` which has some `LinkButtons` which redirects to another page with `QueryString`. On click, it is redirecting to the other page with `QueryString`.

If I right click on the `LinkButton` inside the `DataList` and try to open in new tab, only a blank page is opening.

Guys, if you have some solution regarding this please help me!

Comment: Where are you setting redirect page's URL, in code behind or in LinkButton control itself? Can you post some code for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void linkbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var link = sender as LinkButton;
    string url = link.Link;
    Process.Start(url);
}
```

Try this. The problem may be that you are unable to supply the `url` for process in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click"
  onclientclick=" window.open(&quot;~/Login.aspx&quot;, &quot;List&quot;, &quot;scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=280&quot;)">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```